# Reference about the conformal metric on a compact Riemann surface.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Given a compact Riemann surface on which one is given a conformal metric $ds^2$. In terms of a local holomorphic coordinate $w$ on $S$, $ds^2 = h(w)|dw|^2$ and the Gaussian curvature is $K(w) = \frac{-4}{h(w)}\frac{\partial^2 logh(w)}{\partial w \partial \bar w}$.

Are there any references on the conformal metric of a Riemann surface? I am familiar with Rieamnnian geometry and one-variable complex analysis. We have been through some very basics of the Rieamann surface in class.

Comment: Have a look at the first two chapters of "Complex Analysis: The Geometric  Viewpoint" by Steven G. Krantz. Its freely available online.

Comment: could also try jost's compact riemann surface